Export object (obj, gltf, fbx,...) not saving textures
I have a problem that I have been unable to solve for several days. When I export an object retrieved via game assets, the images disappear, whereas if I perform the same action with a simple cube, it works.
I have tried many actions following my research on various posts, videos, etc. But nothing works, none of the solutions I have explored have worked.
Problem: I can't properly export the textures of my object.
What happened: During the export, no images are included in the export.
What should have happened: There should be a link between the materials and the images via the "map_Kd" property in the mtl file.
Solutions explored:

Export with the "COPY" option
Pack/Unpack image files and export the object behind the texture folder
Export the object in different formats (obj, fbx, gltf, dae)
Export the object via a python script in different formats (obj, fbx, gltf)
...

Version: Blender 3.6
Evidence: YT Video: Export object (obj, gltf, fbx, ...) not saving textures [Blender 3.6]
EDIT: With your various responses coupled with my research, I have partially corrected my problem; now I just need to optimize my solution. I transformed the "custom" shaders into "Principled BSDF" and it works. Now I just need to choose the right shader for each "custom" shader.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures
